# What to do when american wheat ale turned out to have too high extract?

Tags: all-grain, efficiency, wheat-beer

I [used to have a problem](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/q/16311/12577) - too much water due to extracting every last bit of sugar. That gave me 90% to 95% efficiency, but also it was a lot of work to boil it down to manageable and usable amounts of wort.

This time I aimed at 70%. I created my grain bill to target 12 Brix (around 1.048 OG). It was simple, 2.5 kg pale ale and 2.5 kg wheat malts. I only sparged to get my 30 liters of preboil volume and then let the rest go to the sink. "Sadly", it turned out I did things generally better and yet again - I hit about 16 Brix (1.065) at the end. It seems I still managed to get 90% to 95% sugars, in less water. Good thing, but:

1. I do not have capabilities to pitch two fermentors now.
2. I plainly refuse to waste such a good wort.
3. For [american wheat](http://www.bjcp.org/2008styles/style06.php#1d) it'll be too strong. And I really wanted it to be a session beer.

On the bright side, hops I added should bring it to around 35 IBU (here I was intentionally out of style), so even with increased maltiness it should be balanced.

What are my options now? Is fermenting it as is a good way? Do I really have any alternatives?

---

It was time and past time to pitch it, but I still want to know what I could have done. Answers telling focusing on fermentation as is would be especially valuable, but I'll appreciate all of them - even ones I can't use *now*.

Comment: Nice problem to have.  Have you tried planning for 90% efficiency in your recipe calculations?

Comment: @Rube I did, until now. But then I always ended up with way too much water. Long boils was inconvenient.  This time I decided to discard weak sparge water and limit boil to 90 minutes. But my sparge efficiency (sugar to water ratio) increased compared to all previous batches. Surprisingly.

Comment: @Rube if only my sparge went as poorly as the one that inspired previous  question, my plan would be perfect ;)

Comment: what calculator/ method do you use for determining mash/sparge water amounts?

Comment: @Rube For mash, intuition and style description. For sparge - over 3 Brix I take. Yesterday I did different - take as much as I need to get pregnant boil  volume I want. Turned our all the same.

Comment: Something doesn't seem right here. When did you take your gravity reading?  And how are you calculating your efficiency%?  Its not easy to get that high an efficiency.  And to still get it after you changed things up to limit it still seems odd.

Comment: @brewchez I use BrewTarget with malt data from malting house. I measure after boil, when I know my volume, and compare. I use both refractometer and traditional floating meter.

Comment: hmmm... so are you not taking a preboil gravity of the well mixed wort?   I'd be careful of the malt data unless you are totally sure you have data on your specific lot.  Although it really should change much lot to lot.  And you are totally sure of your pre and post volume data.  Meaning you are accurate on how much water went into the mash, how much volume came out of the mash.  What's your boil off rate (or at least your pre/post boil volumes)?

Comment: @brewchez I'm sure about data of my malt, these are pretty consistent, documents are updated fairly often, and I always can ask for specific data - but it never changes significantly. And yes, I'm sure about my volumes. Especially about post-boil. Preboil and boiloff does not really matter, what matters is how much sugar I have when I reach target volume - and it's too much.

Comment: OK. If your confident, then I am too.  I only mention the pre and post boil thing because I find it easier to conceptualize the mash stats when I only think pre boil.  But if you have accurate #s all around it doesn't matter.  I guess what you are left with is loosening your crush or modifying your sparge process to limit that crazy good efficiency.  If you try and limit your grain for a 90-95% efficiency I think your malt character will suffer.  Generally, lower efficiency worts carry more malt flavors.  Going to far the other way and you'll be upset for other reasons.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there was much you could do on the fermentation side to fix anything.  I'd still have planned ferment it out, plan to dry hop it heavily to try and create a little more balance.  Then I'd learn form the experience and get ready to re-brew the beer I wanted to brew.

To limit your efficiency, you could sparge a little faster or ease up on the degree of your crush.  Hard to say as we don't know why your efficiency is so high.  (Too high some may say for making great beer.)

If you wanted a 1.048 beer your could have diluted an appropriate volume of the 1.065 wort down to 1.048.  I would have maybe saved the rest for use in starter wort. That way you wouldn't feel so bad tossing out wort.  You need to consider the cost of the wort in time and money.  It really isn't that big a deal to toss out a gallon or a few quarts.  The time and money spent re-brewing later to get the beer you want should out way the costs of that small amount of wort to toss.

Comment: Actually, I wasn't able to speed up sparge. I always sparged faster, but addidion of wheat slowed it down for me - and that was my mistake in planning. I opened valve to it's full, and it still went slow.